# OAUTH Authorization Code Grant on Angular/Ionic Mobile App with ADFS

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, oauth

I am trying to authenticate an Angular/Ionic Mobile Application with ADFS3.0 by following instructions in
https://github.com/nordvall/TokenClient/wiki/OAuth-2-Authorization-Code-grant-in-ADFS

ADFS supports only Authorization Code Grant. So, for Authorization Code Grant, how to set up the Mobile Client that will handle the Redirect URI and get the access token. 
I am getting confused what to do in cases of Ionic/Angular Apps.

Thanks
Sourav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That question is too broad. So I give you a broad answer. We used Auth0 and their documentation and feautre-set is absolutely excellent and up to latest of Ionic 2 Release. With only 2 lines of code you can use their widget in your app.

https://auth0.com/

Comment: Thanks. I apologize for the broad question. I looked into Auth0 Website for Executing Authorization Code Grants and found the relevant code.

Comment: Glad you found the answer helpful. Their forums are good as well.